# AJAX post in Play Framework

Tags: ajax, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

Hi I'm trying to send a string to my method in play framework but after clicking the submit button i get 500 (Internal Server Error)error in my console. here is my frontend code :

```
 $("#submit").click( function() {
 $.ajax({
    url: "@routes.Application.upload()",
    data: JSON.stringify(filename),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(res) {
      if (res) {
        console.log("Success!");
      } else {
        console.log("Failed...");
      }
    }
  });

   return false;
});
```

my form:

```
    <form id="#idForm">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
            <input id="submit" type="submit">
        </form>
```

and here is my upload method

```
 public static Result upload() {
    JsonNode node = request().body().asJson().get("stringField");
    String inputString = node.asText();
    System.out.println(inputString) ; }
```

Can you help me with this please.

Comment: You are trying to post data .. to a function? url: "@routes.Application.upload()", <- maybe try a real url.

Comment: @britter  @routes.Application.upload() is basically /upload in play. I tried both it gives me same error `POST http://127.0.0.1:9000/upload 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Can you show the error you get from the server? You can look at the console output or if you are using Chrome or Firefox check the Network in dev tools

Comment: Also try to annotate your "upload" method with `@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)`

Comment: @Salem this play console error `[error] play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: java.lang.Null
PointerException
[error] application -

! @6l4i8c1p2 - Internal server error, for (POST) [/upload] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[NullPointerException: null]]`

Comment: @Salem and this is chrome error `POST http://127.0.0.1:9000/upload 500 (Internal Server Error)jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4 n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.sendjquery-2.1.3.min.js:4 n.extend.ajax(index):117 (anonymous function)jquery-2.1.3.min.js:3 n.event.dispatchjquery-2.1.3.min.js:3 n.event.add.r.handle`

Comment: @HiradRoshandel Check that you are really sending a JSON object with the structure you are trying to parse in the server. It should be something like `{"stringField": "some value"}`. If it is different post an example of what you are trying to send

Comment: @Salem this is what I'm sending `{"stringField":"Configs20150204133302"}` but apparently in the server side request().body().asJson() is null

Comment: @HiradRoshandel have you tried sending a normal string instead of json.To check if ajax is working properly

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send string how about changing the `input type="text"` in your form and serializing your form with `serializeArray` outside ajax function like this `var formData = JSON.stringify($("#idForm").serializeArray());` and inside ajax function set `data: formData` also `contentType : "application/json"`. Inside your upload() in controller.
`JsonNode formValue=request().body().asJson();`
`String jsonValue =formValue.findValue("value").textValue();`
Check if this works.